# Finding place value in ruby

Tags: ruby, math

I'm trying to research this simple operation, and I'm coming up with nothing for it. I want to be able to find a place value for an integer, and I'm wondering if there is a specific gem or operation for it. For example:

```
a = 1651684651
p find_place_value_of(a,5) # imaginary function to return the value of the
                           #  number in the 10000 column
                           #  output should be 8
```

So far the best I have been able to do is come up with this ugly little function:

```
j= 262322
a= j 
a/=100000 
b= j - a*100000
b/=10000 
c= j - a*100000 - b*10000 
c/=1000 
d= j - a*100000 - b*10000 - c*1000 
d/=100 
e= j - a*100000 - b*10000 - c*1000 - d*100
e/=10 
f= j - a*100000 - b*10000 - c*1000 - d*100 - e*10
p a,b,c,d,e,f,j
```

Is there a more elegant way of finding a place value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert the integer to a string and then get the character in the nth position.

```
a.to_s[5] #=> '8'
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to resort to strings then you could use

```
def value_at_position(number, position, base=10)
  (number % (base**position))/(base**(position-1))
end
```

If you wanted the answer in a different base, then pass the extra argument:

```
value_at_position(1651684651,5) #=> 8
value_at_position(1651684651,5,8) #=> 3, since 1651684651 is 14234532453 in base 8
```

Comment: Fredericks solution is the real one. When one asks about digits, one should not rely on #to_s implementation.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I'm curious why `to_s` would be considered unreliable... Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @DarshanComputing: It's just linguistics. #to_s says: "To string". Give me a string. It says nothing about digits being in the right place. You know how Ruby is. One dev will subclass `Fixnum` to `class DollarSum < Fixnum`, and rewrite #to_s method to show "$20" instead of "20", and you are dependent. Another dev will write `module Douglas; def to_s; return 'meaning of universe' if self == 42; super end end` and then `class Fixnum; prepend Douglas end`, and `42.to_s` will give wrong answer. `to_s` solution will do in most practical situations, but this is about virtuous development habits.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Thanks for elaborating.  I see where you're coming from.  Of course, folks can just as well override the arithmetic operators as `to_s`, but I suppose that's less likely to be run into.  In any case, thanks for sharing your rationale.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Charles' technique, but I *think* you're considering a "place" as 1-indexed from the right rather than 0-indexed from the left.  Inconveniently, your example number and desired output leave that ambiguous.  In case my hunch is right, here's an elaboration on Charles' technique that would do what you want:

```
def find_place_value_of(num, place)
  num.to_s.reverse[place-1].to_i
end

a = 1651684651
p find_place_value_of(a, 5) # => 8
p find_place_value_of(a, 4) # => 4
```